# how to get device id (player id) using php for onesignal browser push notification?

Tags: php, curl, onesignal

I want to add custom tags for the users who subscribed my website's notification. But to do so I need their playerid and I'm unable to fetch that spcific user's playerid.

```
<?php
$fields = array( 
'app_id' => 'app_id', 
'tags' => array('user_id' => ''.$user_id.'','user_email' => ''.$user_email.'','tag3' => ''.$tag3.'','tag4' => ''.$tag4.'',)
); 
$fields = json_encode($fields); 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players/'.$playerID); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

$resultData = json_decode($response, true);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call [getUserId](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/website-sdk-api#getUserId) from the OneSignal javascript to get the player id from your browser.

```
OneSignal.push(function() {
  OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) {
    console.log("OneSignal User ID:", userId);
    // (Output) OneSignal User ID: 270a35cd-4dda-4b3f-b04e-41d7463a2316    
  });
});
```

Comment: and how would I access that userId in php?

Comment: @jkasten - I have devices GCM id( pushnotificationID ) in my database, can i  use this as player ID in oneSignal?

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing is creating an ajax call in the getUserId callback function which sends the userID as a parameter.

I then store it in my user's session in php and use it when needed.

However I am not sure if there are any drawbacks here.

Answer (score 0):

I have saved player id in database and localstorage
Since this script runs on every page load, so I check if localstorage have player id then I dont send ajax to save it.

```
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async=""></script>
<script>
window.OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];

OneSignal.push(function() {
    OneSignal.init({
        autoResubscribe:true,
        appId: "your_app_id",
        safari_web_id: "your_safari_app_id",
        notifyButton: {
            enable: true,
        },

    });
    if(!localStorage.getItem('player_id')){

        OneSignal.getUserId().then(function(userId) {
            localStorage.setItem('player_id',userId)
            let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            // console.log("OneSignal User ID:", userId);
            // (Output) OneSignal User ID: 270a35cd-4dda-4b3f-b04e-41d7463a2316
            let data = new FormData();
            data.append('player_id', userId);
            xhttp.open('POST','/onesignal/save-player-id',true)
            xhttp.send(data);
        });
    }
});
```

more details [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk#user-ids)